# Connect to iphone hotspot from raspberry pi

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, raspberry-pi

Currently, i can connect from the raspberry (raspbian) to my home wifi but when i try to connect to iphone (4s) hotspot i can't. Iphone is WPA2 Personal while my home network is WPA/WPA2 Personal. I suspect there's something wrong with my config but i really can't find what. Here's the relevant part in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

```
network={
    ssid="iPhone"
    psk="pass"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
 }
```

For reference here's the config (working) for my home network (in the same file):

```
network={
    ssid="wifi name"
    psk="pass"
    # Protocol type can be: RSN (for WP2) and WPA (for WPA1)
    proto=WPA
    # Key management type can be: WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP (Pre-Shared or Enterprise)
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    # Pairwise can be CCMP or TKIP (for WPA2 or WPA1)
    pairwise=TKIP
    #Authorization option should be OPEN for both WPA1/WPA2 (in less commonly used are SHARED and LEAP)
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your network has not the same configuration as you set (for `proto` / `pairwise`). You might configure your network this way:

```
network={
    ssid="iPhone"
    psk="pass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 }
```

The *wpa_supplicant* will find the correct configuration by itself.

Comment: Yup. Thanks, it seems that config was overly complicated :)

Comment: wpa_supplicant is located in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: In elementary OS it doesn't allow me to edit this file, i think it confuses it as it's own system file or something (I'm a beginner at Linux). what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove inverted commas & spaces from your iphone’s Name this will solve the problem

Comment: What makes you think that there are any? Also could you explain how they cause the problem?